# Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C, and Ctrl-V are not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

It looks like it's affecting every application. I have tried uninstalling the keyboard driver as follows:

1. From the Start Menu, I searched for Device Manager, and opened it.
2. In Device Manager I navigated to the Keyboard Standard 101/102, and uninstalled the driver
3. Rebooted.

Comment: No, Ctrl+D doesn't work either...

Comment: Is it possible that your Control key is broken? Have you tried both Control keys (left and right)?

Comment: Yes, with both, I have the same behavior

Comment: Try running the on-screen-keyboard. (1) Press your “Ctrl” keys, and see whether they light up in the screen image. (2) *Use* the on-screen-keyboard program to generate Ctrl-key combinations, and see what they do. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to have fixed it:
(The steps 1, and 2 I described when I posted the issue)

3. I shut down my laptop.
4. I removed the battery, and after unplugging my laptop, I waited 15s.
5. After rebooting, all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> combinations started working again...